# Cannot deserialize RestResponse with RestSharp C#

Tags: c#, json, rest, restsharp

I am trying to deserialize JSON to C# object but not able to get rid of this compiler error. Any help would be much appreciated.

JSON

```
{
  AX:{BX:1777} 
}
```

Here are my deserializer classes:

Response.cs

```
{
    public class Response
    {
        public AX Ax { get; set; }
    }
}
```

AX.cs

```
{
    public class AX
    {
        public long Bx { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the line that is problematic:

```
IRestResponse<Response> response = client.Execute<Response>(request);
```

response.Content is just as fine and returns the raw JSON but I want it to be an instance of the Response class. I want to access Bx like this:

```
var price = response.Ax.Bx; // should return 1777
```

But this line produces the following compiler error:

```
Error: IRestResponse does not contain definition for 'Ax'
```

Comment: Can you try `Response response = client.Execute<Response>(request);` ? By saying IRestResponse<Response>, you are casting to a type of IRestResponse and you might not have Ax field defined in the IRestResponse interface.

Comment: Yes but I was getting a different error.

Comment: Well I have Ax field in the Response Class. I thought that's where it was supposed to be at.

Comment: Yes that's where it needs to be. Just going through their documentation (http://restsharp.org/), looks like you need to use `RestResponse<Response> response = client.Execute<Response>(request);` and not `IRestResponse` interface. Please check if this helps

Comment: I already tried this as well. Initially cast explicitly but in vain. the same error persists.

Comment: try this `IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(response.Content);
            var price = obj.Ax.Bx;`

Comment: you need to access `Content` property of `IRestResponse` and after deserialize this content into your `Response` object to get price like i did in above comment

Comment: Can you inspect the response object ? It looks like the actual response is a level inside the response object. Instead of `response.Ax.Bx` try `response.Data.Ax.Bx`

Comment: You might have done a character casing error. The property in your Response class is named Ax (with lower case x) but the property name in the result JSON is named AX (with upper case X)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with case sensitive. RestSharp serializer expects following json structure

```
{
  Ax:{Bx:1777} 
}
```

You have 3 ways to deal with it:

1) add DataContract and DataMember to your classes

```
[DataContract]
public class Response
{
    [DataMember(Name = "AX")]
    public AX Ax { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class AX
{
    [DataMember(Name = "BX")]
    public long Bx { get; set; }
}
```

2) write your own serializer that ignores case sensitive and use it with restsharp

3) change your json structure

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, and having spent some time searching around this, I would have used Newtonsoft.Json and solved it like this:

```
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
string ResponseStr = response.Content.ToString();
dynamic Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(ResponseStr);
```

you can then call off the elements as you need them:

```
var price = Response.AX.BX;
string Description = Response.AX.Desc.ToString();     etc
```

Hope this helps someone